# How to get the current route from react without props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to get the show/hide a button in react based on the route.

In home.js, I'm rendering the following:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={()=> <TotalStuff totalStuff={totalStuff} />} />
<Link to="/addStuff"><button>Add Stuff</button></Link>
<Route path="/addStuff" exact component={AddStuff} />
```

When route is "/" it simply renders addStuff component with Add stuff button and some text content.

But I want to hide the "Add Stuff" button in the **AddStuff** component.

When trying with window.location.pathname, it is not getting updated with change in router.

Also I tried with **withRouter**. But I'm looking for a better direct approach if any.

Thanks.

Comment: I used to do that simply by adding an ngIf in angular 2+. As I'm new to react, I was trying the possible alternatives to ngIf and arrived at this unsuccessful attempt. As per docs and Stackoerflow previous solutions, I tried withRouter, but as mentioned, I was looking any simple/direct approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the `Link` inside the `render` prop function of the first `Route` component to make it not show on the `/addStuff` path.

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/"
  render={() => (
    <div>
      <TotalStuff totalStuff={totalStuff} />
      <Link to="/addStuff">
        <button>Add Stuff</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  )}
/>
<Route path="/addStuff" exact component={AddStuff} />
```

Comment: Your solution serves the purpose and that is what I wanted. But when I was trying this way(getting the current router path and hiding) I was not successful.

Comment: @betaprogrammers Alright. Did you try using [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) and looking at the `props.location.pathname`?